# How to resolve error in nextjs when API(post method) JSON information not show in database?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, postman

## POST METHODE-

```
export  async function POST(request){
    // FETCH USER DETAIL FROM REQUEST METHOD
   const {name,email,password,about,profileURL} = await request.json();
   console.log({name,email,password,about,profileURL});
   // crate user object with user model

   const users = new User({
    name,
    email,
    password,
    about,
    profileURL,
});

try{

    //save the object to the database
    const craetedUser = await users.save();
    const response = NextResponse.json(users,{
    status:201,
    });

    return response;
}catch(errrr){
    console.log(errrr);
     return NextResponse.json({
           message:"failed to create user",
           status:false,
     });
}
}
```

**database db.js file**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import { User } from "../models/user";
export const connectDB = async()=> {

    try{
        const {connection} = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB_url,{
            dbname:"work-manager",
        });
        console.log("db connected");

  //testing and creating
const uuser = new User({
    name:"test1 name",
    email:"test1@gmail.com",
    password:"test1 password",
    about:"this is testing1",
});
// const uuser2 = new User({
//     name:"test2 name",
//     email:"test2@gmail.com",
//     password:"test2 password",
//     about:"this is testing2",
// });

await uuser.save();
// await uuser2.save();
console.log("user is created");

     console.log("connected with",connection.host);
    }catch(error){
     console.log("Error in the database connection");
     console.log(error);
    }
};
```

## When I pass the below JSON information the below error comes.

**JSON pass through POSTMAN-**

```
{
    "name":"kunal",
    "email":"kunalrocky46@gmail.com",
    "password":"kunal",
    "profileURL":"http://localhost:3000",
    "about":"here we craetting user"
}
```

**Error**

```
db connected
{
  name: 'kunal',
  email: 'kunalrocky46@gmail.com',
  password: 'kunal',
  about: 'here we craetting user',
  profileURL: 'http://localhost:3000'
}
 ⨯ ReferenceError: User is not defined
    at POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/api/user/route.js:45:18)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63809
    at async eU.execute (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53964)
    at async eU.handle (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:65062)
    at async doRender (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1315:42)
    at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1537:28)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1445:28)
    at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1842:24)
    at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:1880:32)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:893:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:269:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:789:17)
    at async C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:331:20
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:151:20)
    at async DevServer.handleRequest (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:328:24)
    at async invokeRender (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:174:21)
    at async handleRequest (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:353:24)
    at async requestHandlerImpl (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-server.js:377:13)
    at async Server.requestListener (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\MERN_STACK\NextJS\work-manager\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:140:13)
user is created
connected with ac-1yevrzu-shard-00-01.0hyxtxl.mongodb.net
 ✓ Compiled in 533ms (502 modules)
```

## Next.JS and MongoDB are an excellent combination to help you get your next application up and running. A Next JS MongoDB connection will make it easy to move data from the database and render it on the application. In this article, we will discuss the steps for Next JS MongoDB Connection.

## Next.js is a popular open-source React framework for building web applications. It is designed to simplify creating robust and efficient React applications by providing a set of conventions and tools. Next.js offers server-side rendering (SSR), automatic code splitting, and an intuitive file-based routing system.

Comment: Maybe you are missing the User import in the first file?

Comment: I did but it's not working